# Japanese IME conversion candidates in English

Tags: windows-10, language, ime, japanese

I have the Japanese IME for Windows 10 installed, and that's what I'm using. I'm using the previous version, because whenever I try to use the current version it constantly tells me the IME is not ready yet and to check the status in language settings (but that's a separate issue; I also can't find anywhere how to check the current version, so if someone could tell me that in the comments I'd appreciate it). Using the romaji input method works fine (case in point: わたし). I'm asking here because this feels like it has more to do with the IME than the Japanese.

Whenever I try to convert something, all the conversion candidates are in English, or just what I already typed in romaji. For example, when I type わたし, the first candidate is `"watashi"` and the second candidate is `Watashe`, but 私 never shows up. It works a little differently for certain words, like きょう and ことし, which will actually suggest things like `2/21/2024` and `2024年`, but it won't give me the the actual words 今日 and 今年.

How do I fix this?